# I cannot seem to connect to GoogleAPI Client, there is no connection, neither is there a failure

Tags: java, android, google-api

So I am trying to connect to the `Google API client`, but I am not getting a response from my `onConnected` method or `onConnectionFailed` method.  Both methods are like so, respectively:

```
 public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

    Log.d(TAG, "OnConnected");

    if (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ==
            (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mParentBase, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)))

    {
        Log.d(TAG, "Permission Was Granted" );
        mMyLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

        if (mMyLocation == null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, requestLocation, mParentIntent);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, mMyLocation.toString());
        }
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(mParentActivity, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        Log.d(TAG, "Permission Was Requested" );
    }

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    Log.i(TAG, "Connection Failed");

    if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
            connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(mParentActivity, CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG, "Location services connection failed with code " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
    }
```

}

I have a public interface that starts the connection to the API:

```
public void connect()
    {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        Log.d(TAG, "Connection Requested");
    }
```

I can see the above log output file on Android Studio **Run Console**.

Has anyone else seen this type of problem?

Edit:
Code to build and initialise the client

```
public myLocation(Context Base, Activity activitiyBase, PendingIntent intent) {
        mParentBase = Base;
        mParentActivity = activitiyBase;
        mParentIntent = intent;
        initialLocationService();
    }

    /**
     *  Initialize the Location Service and API Client
     */

    private void initialLocationService(){
         mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mParentBase)
             .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
             .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
             .addApi(LocationServices.API)
             .build();

         requestLocation = LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
            .setInterval(10*1000)
            .setFastestInterval(1*1000);
```

the class implements the following:

```
public class myLocation implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback,
        LocationListener
{
```

Comment: watch your log for errors and post it if you find any.

Comment: I think the most important code to post would be the code that builds your `GoogleApiClient`.  If that's not correct, you won't get to these callbacks.

Comment: @Nidhi, there were no errors in the log

Comment: @Gary99 added code that builds the client

Comment: Do you have your permissions correct in the Manifest file?  Otherwise, all of this looks similar to the way that I'm using `GoogleApiClient`.  I'm doing everything, building and callbacks in a service so it is all in the same Context, this is the only significant difference I see from your code.  Could you try doing `myLocation` as an Activity to see if that fixes your problem?  That would give you `mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)`...

Comment: @Gary99 I do have the following permission defined

Comment: @Gary99  myLocation is already a class.  I can't use this w/o having an error so I used the base of the main activity.

Comment: Sorry.  Don't have time to look into it more now.  I'll try to get back to it tomorrow.

Comment: @Gary99 LOL it's ok.  It is New Years Eve, happy New Year btw.

Comment: @Gary99  Sorry to bother you, I was wondering if there is a variable in the ApiClient object that can track the status of the connection, I tried debugging with breakpoints, to look at the state of the variables but I can't seem to find any indication with what is going on the connection to the API.

Comment: You can try `isConnecting()` or `isConnectionCallbacksRegistered`.  Take a look at https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.  I have been looking at your problem this morning but nothing of use to suggest to you yet.

Answer (score 0):

OK.  I've put together some code that I hope will help you find your problem.  I have this code as a working app on a device.  I've used a mix of your code with mine.  By comparing the differences, you should be able to narrow down your problem.  1st myLocation class...

```
public class myLocation implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback,
        LocationListener {

    private final static String TAG = "myLocation";
    private final static int MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 1;
    private final static long ONE_SECOND = 1000;
    private final static long UPDATE_INTERVAL = ONE_SECOND;
    private final static long FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL = ONE_SECOND;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = null;
    Context mParentBase;
    Activity mParentActivity;

    public myLocation(Context Base, Activity activitiyBase) {
        mParentBase = Base;
        mParentActivity = activitiyBase;
        initialLocationService();
    }

    // you call this an interface in your question but I'm just
    //     making it a public method which can be called from Activity
    public void connect()
    {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        Log.d(TAG, "Connection Requested");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

        Log.d(TAG, "OnConnected");

        if (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ==
                (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mParentBase,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)))

        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Permission Was Granted");
            startLocationUpdates();
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(mParentActivity,
                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    MY_PERMISSION_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
            Log.d(TAG, "Permission Was Requested");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection Failed");
        // just logging for now
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, 
            @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        // loading from Android Studio, not going to worry about this now
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection Suspended");
        // just logging for now, not trying to resolve failure
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Entered the onLocationChanged() method");
        // this calls one or the other private methods that don't
        //    matter to your problem.  I can post them if you like.
        if (location != null) {
            showLocationInfo(location);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Can't get last location");
            setAllUnavailable();
        }
    }

    private void initialLocationService() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(mParentBase)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();
        }
    }

    private void locationRequestUpdates(long interval, long fastestInterval, int priority) {
        // remove any previous updates
        try {
            if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
               .removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
            }
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            logException("SecurityException", e);
        }

        // build a new request
        LocationRequest locationRequest = new LocationRequest()
                .setInterval(interval)
                .setFastestInterval(fastestInterval)
                .setPriority(priority);

        // now send new request
        try {
            if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                        mGoogleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
            }
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            logException("SecurityException", e);
        }
    }

    private void startLocationUpdates() {
        Location lastLocation = null;
        try {
            lastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
                    mGoogleApiClient);
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            logException("SecurityException", e);
        }

        if (lastLocation != null) {
            showLocationInfo(lastLocation);
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Can't get last location");
            setAllUnavailable();
        }

        locationRequestUpdates(UPDATE_INTERVAL,
                FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL,
                LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }
}
```

In the Activity, in `onCreate()`...

```
mMyLocation = new myLocation(getApplicationContext(), this);
```

and in `onStart()`...

```
mMyLocation.connect();
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the code.  I am still having issue.  So far the problem is that the Client is stuck in connecting state.  I logged the connection status, and I also logged if the callback is registered.

Comment: boolean connecting = mCurrentLocation.mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting();
            boolean registered = mCurrentLocation.mGoogleApiClient.isConnectionCallbacksRegistered(mCurrentLocation);
            //ConnectionResult connectionResult = mCurrentLocation.mGoogleApiClient.getConnectionResult(LocationServices.API);

            if (connecting == TRUE) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Connecting");
            }

            if (registered == TRUE) {
                Log.d(TAG, "registered");
            }

Comment: Sorry the above is a mess but here is the output:

Comment: D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: registered
D/selectRouteAndTransportMethod: Connecting

Comment: Have you checked the version of Google Play Services?  The version you have in your library dependencies must be less than or equal to what is on your device.  I would expect that to cause a more obvious problem for you but it should be confirmed.

Comment: Also, is the issue you are still having with your code or have you tried the code I've posted?

Comment: I have tried both, how do I find the version of google play services on the device?

Comment: Right now I am using 10.0.1 running on API 23

Comment: Nevermind, checked the App on the phone, it is 10.0.84

Comment: Do you know the timeout period is for initiating a connection, can that be modified?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about the timeout period.  I was able to get my code to work so if it doesn't work for you, there's something different about the device, location, network, configuration, etc. that's probably your problem.  I doubt I will be able to help in that case.

Comment: One last comment, I'm using `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'`.  I have some older devices that I want to support.  (It still works on my API 23 device though).  If nothing else, you can try going back to an older version of the library.

Comment: Ok how do I download an older version of google play?

Comment: also thanks for your help, it's greatly appreciated :), I know this is an unusual conundrum, I have scowered the internet for this